# python bind code not working as expected

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

Why does the following code not produce the expected result?:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def key(event):
    frame.focus_set()
    print "pressed", repr(event.char
frame = Frame(root, width=100, height=100)
frame.bind("<Key>", key)
frame.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: print "pressed", repr(event.char) that the name of the key pressed is printed.

Comment: Missing parenthesis, perhaps?

Comment: Was in the original code. Just an oversight in pasting it to the board.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set input focus to your frame.
Try adding `frame.focus_set()` before

```
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! That is the solution. Have a great weekend.

Comment: @BobPynewby you are welcome. Please don't forget to mark the answer as resolution.